# Terraform destroy to be done internally

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I have a project that creates resources on Google Cloud Platform (GCP) using Terraform. I need a way to automatically delete all the resources created by Terraform once a lock file exists on a GCP bucket.

Is it possible to write code in my Terraform files that will delete these resources when the lock file is detected? This is important because this project is part of a continuous integration and delivery (CICD) pipeline, and I don't have the ability to manually trigger a Terraform destroy command. Additionally, these resources are no longer needed once certain operations are complete.

Comment: "no control to manually give a terraform destroy" - what does it mean? You can't execute such a comment? Then how do you want to destroy the resources?

Comment: The exact scenario is I am bringing up certain VM in order to perform certain operations through terraform.After those operations I don’t want the resources to be hanging in running state.I can take care of these deletion through cloud commands but that doesn’t really update state file .so is there a way we can delete the resources internally so that the state file is also updated.No control meaning these are part of cicd tool and cannot execute any commands manually.

Comment: There is [state rm](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/state/rm) which you can delete resources from the state file. Not sure this is what you are after?

Answer (score 0):

Terraform takes actions only when run explicitly by you. Terraform is not a long-running service, so it cannot take any unattended actions.